# Nginx Replace characters in hostname

Tags: nginx, redirect, replace, url-rewriting, hostname

I have urls like this:

> - https://foo.somedomain.com
> - https://foo.bar.somedomain.com
> - https://foo.bar.baz.somedomain.com
> - and so on

And I want nginx to replace dots "." characters in the subdomain part of the hostname by dashes "-", so this would result in :

> - https://foo.somedomain.com
> - https://foo-bar.somedomain.com
> - https://foo-bar-baz.somedomain.com
> - and so on

I already have a server block that catches the urls with dots in the "prefix" variable, but I could not find any documentation on how to rewrite url so that is replaces characters in "prefix" without using lua/...:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name "~^(?<prefix>[\w\.]+).somedomain.com$";

    rewrite 302 "$scheme://What do i put in here?.somedomain.com$request_uri";
}
```

A big thanks for people that will try to help on this!

Answer (score 1):

You could capture both sides of the `.` with separate captures, for example:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name ~^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.example\.com$;

    ...

    return 302 $scheme://$1-$2-$3.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name ~^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.example\.com$;

    ...

    return 302 $scheme://$1-$2.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a map to capture the subdomains:

```
map $host $resub {
    ~^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.somedomain\.com$ $1-$2;
    ~^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.somedomain\.com$ $1-$2-$3;
    ~^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.somedomain\.com$ $1-$2-$3-$4;
    ~^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.somedomain\.com$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5;
    # etc.
}

server {
    server_name  *.somedomain.com;

    if ($resub) {
        return 302 $scheme://$resub.somedomain.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```